# AWS EC2 public vs private IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

Is there any difference in using private and public IPs for communicating with other AWS instances? Do private IPs provide any more functionality(or security) as compared to using public IPs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few differences:

- Instances launched in a VPC, the private IP address remains associated with the network interface when the instance is stopped and restarted. The public IP would get released when you stop and restart unless you use Elastic IP.
- If you have a pure backend-service, you could give it only a private IP and create a VPN connection into your VPC. That way, an attacker would not be able to even contact your backend-service unless he gained access to your VPN.
- Using the private IP doesn't result in bandwidth charges.

So deploy your EC2 instance in the VPC, so that it gets a static internal IP. If you like, set up an Elastic IP. If you resolve the Elastic IP from the internal network, you will get the private IP and the public IP when resolved from externally. https://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal/